# How to post JSON Object direct using Retrofit in android Kotlin (Using MVVM Pattern)

Tags: android, mvvm, retrofit

I am using retrofit for posting data to server as below

```
  @POST("web_php/app_user_login")
    suspend fun loginApi(@Body body: RequestBodies.LoginRequestBody): Response<LoginResponse>
```

```
 data class LoginRequestBody(
        val user_name: String,
        val user_password: String
    )
```

But I want to post JSON Object directly just like as below

```
 data class CreateAuditRequestBody(
        val auditJsonObject: JSONObject
    )
```

```
  @POST("web_php/create_first_audit")
    suspend fun createAuditApi(@Body body: RequestBodies.CreateAuditRequestBody): Response<CreateAuditResponse>
```

But It gives an error. Kindly Help me.
Thanks

Comment: `But It gives an error. ` what's the error ? have you researched it ? what did you find ?

Comment: The parameter you pass is incorrect, the error given by Server API. Actually, it works perfect when I, use volley, but I do not know how to use it with retrofit

Comment: there are tons of resources online for using retrofit